# jsonPath return string without brackets

Tags: json, groovy, jsonpath

I have the following code:

```
responseBody =     '[{"properties":{"gridProperties":{"columnCount":26,"rowCount":1000},"index":3,"sheetId":1682983530,"sheetType":"GRID","title":"kamasi"}}]';

  
def jsonPathSearch = "sheets[?(@.properties.title=='kamasi')].properties"
def foundString = JsonPath.read(responseBody, jsonPathSearch)

println foundString.sheetId;
```

but it returns [1682983530], not 1682983530. It this possible to get 1682983530 without having to get the first element of the array such as `foundString.sheetId[0]` ? I know that there will be definitely only one element since the title of the sheet has to be unique

Comment: just add `[0]` to get first element of the array

Comment: so there is no possibility to return it directly as a string, right ?

Comment: I don't get it, if I use the following jsonpath: ``def jsonFieldName = "sheets[?(@.properties.title=='kamasi')].length()`` I also end up with an array : [1]. Why doesn't it return an integer ?

Comment: obviously `sheets[...]` returns an array